# How Universal References get deduced

Tags: c++, type-deduction

There is something about `Universal references` really confuses me, I know that

```
T&& + lvalue => T&
T&& + rvalue => T&&
```

Then I heard Scott Meyers says: there is "special rule for universal references" which is:

```
T&& + rvalue => T (NOT T&&)
```

So I did simple test thinking it would clear things up

```
int i = 32;
auto&& v = std::move(i); // assigning xvalue

// According to Scott: auto&& is URef
// And according to the "rule" v should get deduced to T
// VS2015 tells me this is int&& (NOT int)... huh???

auto&& x = int(8); // assigning prvalue
// same as above ... hmmm
```

So what am I missing here ... I really need to understand this...

When `URef` get deduced to to `T&&` and when it get deduced to `T` ... I would appreciated examples to help clear things up ... thanks

Note: I already searched SO I found related questions but didn't find specific answer to this question.

Comment: There are no universal references. It was a terrible term, and the proper word is 'forwarding reference'.

Comment: I know URef and RRef are same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot where you started from. The whole ideea was to see to what `auto` deduces to. It indeed deduces to `int`. And `v` is of type `auto&&`, i.e. `int&&`

Answer (score 3):

If `T` is a template parameter (or `auto`) and `T&&` is used to deduce `T`, then:

- If the argument is an rvalue (xvalue or prvalue) of type `U`, then `T` is deduced to simply `U` and `T&&` is `U&&`.
- If the argument is an lvalue of type `U`, then `T` is deduced to `U&` and `T&&` is `U&&`.

Your confusion probably stems from confusing the type of the template parameter, `T`, with the type of the deduced function argument, `T&&`.

Note that since `T&&` always expands to a reference type, a forwarding reference is indeed a reference and never results in the expression being passed by value.